# Copying range of cells to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a range of cells, say `F10:F59`, of the `Form` sheet, then transpose and paste them to another range on another sheet named `Stock Manual Senin`, say `B11:BA25`.

This is what I currently have:

```js
Sub InputPAGS_Senin()

Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim vntRange As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long

Set copySheet = Sheets("Form")
Set pasteSheet = Sheets("Stock Manual Senin")

' Calculate last row of data.
lastRow = pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

' Copy 2 cells.
pasteSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Offset(0, 1) = copySheet.Range("N2").Value

' Paste column range into array.
vntRange = copySheet.Range("F10:F59").Value

' Paste transpose array into row range.
Sheets("Stock Manual Senin").Select
Range("B11:BA25").Select
pasteSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Offset(0, 3).Resize(, copySheet _
        .Range("F10:F59").Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(vntRange)

End Sub
```

[image: "Manual Stock Senin" Sheet]

[image: result (hilight red)]

the paste target should be in `row 11`, but it'd paste in `row 285` cause target range is located between the others table's row.

Can anyone advise me on how I should continue please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **xlUp Becomes xlDown**

You have to calculate the last row from **NAMA TOKO** down (xlDown). Do not delete **NAMA TOKO** and **PAGS / MIGO**, then you can use the following

```
lastRow = pasteSheet.Cells(9, 2).End(xlDown).Offset(1).Row
```

or even better

```
lastRow = pasteSheet.Cells(9, 2).End(xlDown).Row + 1
```

Comment: Yess...ur Solution helping me Sir @VBasic2008...once again thank you very much.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work? I just did a manual pivot as I wrote out the values.

```
Sub SOTest()
    Dim copySheet       As Worksheet
    Dim CopyRange       As Range
    Dim Cell            As Range
    Dim pasteSheet      As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow         As Long
    Dim ColIndex        As Long

    Set copySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Form")
    Set pasteSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stock Manual Senin")
    Set CopyRange = copySheet.Range("F10:F59")
    ColIndex = 2 'Column B

    With pasteSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Cell In CopyRange
        pasteSheet.Cells(lastRow, ColIndex).Value = Cell.Value
        ColIndex = ColIndex + 1
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the coding Sir @Ryan Wildry..but the result not being in my expected row in `row 11`. It's confusing because the target is located between the others table in same sheet..is there any advise ?